# How to Configure the SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-4.2

I am running my Flutter app in android studio but to solve some problems I have uninstalled Android Studio and downloaded again in my Laptop (MacOS Big Sur- MacBook Air). When I have open the project in new android studio in Logcat I saw in Red `Please configure Android SDK`. Below is the image for more clearity.[image]

When I click on configure, I am getting this below window.
[image]

So I am not geting what I have to do now in project structure.

If anybody has answer the please let me know?

Comment: In SDK Location check that android sdk install and check location is same as your android SDK location if not provide location to android studio

if its same close Android Studio and open project agian

Comment: I have checked that and location is provided where SDK is located. Also restarted Android Studio 2 times but same thing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for the above question and worked for me. I have just updated my `Android Studio` to the newer version. After that I have manually removed the sdk from the computer from the Terminal of Mac and Reinstalled it again.

After that provided the sdk path to the Android Studio and restart the Android Studio. Now run any app on Emulator or real device.

So now this error has gone. If someone is facing this problem then follow these steps.

Answer (score 1):

After changing Build Tool Version on the pop screen

`29 changed into 30   // else selected the highest available version

then click OK started working for me...

(or)

Simply Restart Android Studio File->Invalidate Caches and restart